# Kicked from TNB (by a bot) for "inappropriate content" and have some questions about it

Tags: discussion, chat, flags

I posted an image in the main chat, The Nineteenth Byte.

A few minutes later I get kicked from TNB with a 30 minute ban, and apparently the Community bot did it. How did a bot judge that one picture was worthy of kicking me from chat?

I understand if a human asked me to remove it and I would have immediately but never was asked.

[For moderators who can view the history of a deleted message, here's the link.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/35631789/history)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, some terminology: you weren't kicked out of the The Nineteenth Byte but got a network-wide 30 minute suspension.

The "bot" you mention – Feeds – owns the deletion resulting from six flags (or one from mod) cast on spam, inappropriate, or offensive messages. That gruesome short story certainly fits the bill.

The 30 minutes have passed and your suspension is over. In the future, please refrain from posting content like this in our chat rooms.

Answer (score 6):

Your link was "flagged".

This happens when a user clicks the little "flag" button, near the star and reply button. They found the picture offensive, flagged it as such, and other moderators and 10k+ rep users agreed with that.

It's marked as "Community" deleting it, because it requires multiple people to approve to flag and they're supposed to be anonymous.

Both the flagger and the people who approved the flag are anonymous, so there's no way to tell who did that (as it should be).

Next time, probably don't post that image.  If it could possibly offend anyone, you probably shouldn't post it.